# Vertical spacing in index with idxlayout

Tags: indexing, line-spacing, idxlayout

I have some trouble formatting my index with idxlayout.

As my MWE demonstrates, the **vertical** spacing between the entries is inconsistent. For example the vertical spacing among the entries of entrygroup A is larger than in D. The group themselves are spaced varaibly: D and E are spaced ok, A and B are not.

My real example (which is too large) is even worse. Sometimes the middle column is filled only with 6 lines spread erratically over the column whereas the other lines are filled with more entries.

How do I prevent the rubber spacing and use a **fixed** one?

Optionally: How do I set a penalty which prevents only the group heading from apperaring alone?

Your help is greatly appreciated!

[image: This is the vertically inconsistent index]

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]

\documentclass[%
    12pt,a4paper,twoside,parskip=never,ngerman,headings=normal,]{scrbook} 

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[english,main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{xindystyle.xdy}
(define-location-class "Roman-page-numbers"  ("roman-numbers-uppercase"))
(define-location-class "arabic-page-numbers" ("arabic-numbers")             
                    :min-range-length 1)                        

(define-attributes (("definition" "usage" "default" "hyperpage")))

(define-crossref-class "see")
(markup-crossref-list :class "see" :open "\seelinkk{" :sep "; " :close "}{}")

(define-crossref-class "seealso")
(markup-crossref-layer-list :sep ", ")
(markup-crossref-list :class "seealso" :open "\seealsolinkk{" :sep "; " :close "}{}")

(markup-range :class "arabic-page-numbers" :close "\,f."  :length 1 :ignore-end)
(markup-range :class "arabic-page-numbers" :close "\,ff." :length 2 :ignore-end)
(markup-range :class "arabic-page-numbers" :sep "--")

(define-crossref-class "hyperindexformat")
(markup-crossref-list :class "hyperindexformat" :open
       "\hyperindexformat{" :sep "; " :close "}{}")


(define-location-class-order (
            "Roman-page-numbers"
              "arabic-page-numbers"
              "see"
              "seealso"))

(sort-rule "-" "")

(markup-index :open  "~n\begin{theindex}
                    \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
                    \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
                        \par\textbf{#1}\par
                        \nopagebreak
                    }
                    \newcommand{\targetindexentryy}[1]{\hypertarget{index:#1}{#1}}
                    \newcommand{\seelinkk}[1]{\see{\hyperlink{index:#1}{#1}}}
                    \newcommand{\seealsolinkk}[1]{\seealso{\hyperlink{index:#1}{#1}}}
                ~n"     
    :close "~n~n\end{theindex}~n"
    :tree)

(markup-indexentry :open "~n \item "            :depth 0)
(markup-indexentry :open "~n    \subitem "      :depth 1)
(markup-indexentry :open "~n      \subsubitem " :depth 2)

(markup-locref-list :sep ", ")
(markup-locclass-list :open "\dotfill " :close "" :sep ", ")
(markup-locref :open "\hyperpage{" :close "}")
(markup-locref :open "\hyperpage{" :close "}" :attr "hyperpage")   

(markup-keyword-list :open "\targetindexentryy{" :close "}" )
\end(filecontents)
\usepackage[
]{imakeidx}
    \makeindex[
        columns=3,
        name=person,
        title={Personenverzeichnis},
        program=truexindy,
        options=-M texindy -M page-ranges -M xindystyle -C utf8 -L german-duden,
        ]
\usepackage[%
    totoc=true,
    columns=3,
    itemlayout=abshang,
    unbalanced=true,
    indentunit=0.5cm,
]{idxlayout} % Index layout

\newcommand{\person}[2][]{%
    \ifstrempty{#1}{%
        \textsc{#2\index[person]{#2}}}{%
        \textsc{#2\index[person]{#1}}{}}%
}

\usepackage[%
    hyperindex=false,hypertexnames=true,plainpages=false,breaklinks=true,hidelinks,pageanchor=true,
]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\raggedbottom
    \person{A} \person{Aa} \person{Ab} \person{Ae} \person{B} \person{ba} \person{bbA} \person{bcA} \person{dc} \person{d} \person{ce} \person{dee} \person{fe} \person{ff} \person{few} \person{z} \person{h} \person{eh} \person{erhy} \person{jr} \person{rty} \person{gh} \person{bn} \person{sh} \person{shs} \person{ert} \person{ll} \person{l} \person{fyu} \person{io} \person{erys} \person{syh} \person{yy} \person{ty} \person{jl} \person{ui} \person{pi} \person{oi} \person{m} \person{mn} \person{ji} \person{fh} \person{nn} \person{A} \person{A} \person{A} \person{ttt} \person{tA} \person{eyA} \person{hA} \person{mA} \person{gnA} \person{nnA} \person{nnnA} \person{Amm} \person{Adf} \person{Azds} \person{ssdfA} \person{sdfA} \person{dfghA} \person{dhA} \person{asdas} \person{dsf} \person{d} \person{asdaA} \person{dddaA} \person{asdas} \person{a} \person{asdA} \person{A2} \person{A23} \person{A1} \person{A123} \person{eAf32} \person{A323} \person{A123} \person{A12f3} \person{A123f} \person{A12f3} \person{eA112}\person{etA} \person{ewewA} \person{eeeweA} \person{werA} \person{erwA} \person{eeeA} \person{Asaa} \person{nnnA}  \person{iA} \person{iiA} \person{iiiA} \person{iuA} \person{yiA} \person{dd2A} \person{adA} \person{guA224} 

    \backmatter
    \idxlayout{columns=3}
    \printindex[person]
\end{document}
```

Using a real world example the problem becomes more apparent. I've marked the erratic spaces in red:
[image: real world index example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idxlayout you are using set \parskip to a value with some stretch. You could patch `\theindex` with (after loading idxlayout)

```
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\theindex{\z@ \@plus 0.3\p@}{0pt}{}{\fail}
\makeatother
```

The general space between the letter groups are set by `\indexspace` which you could redefine if you want. But the large spaces between the letter groups are triggered by the hypertargets which seems to suppress pagebreaks. Insert a `\leavevmode` in the definition of `\targetindexentryy`:

```
 \newcommand{\targetindexentryy}[1]{\leavevmode\hypertarget{index:#1}{#1}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer fixed the rubber spacing between the entries. I've added the missing xindystyle.xdy. Do you see any styling inside the .xdy file that influences the spacing before the \lettergroup? I see \indexspace preceeding \lettergroup

Comment: You didn't try your example. Don't use filecontents for this, it adds text at the begin that confuse xindy, use filecontents* instead. Beside this: you document doesn't show a problem with the headers or the letter groups. Without a real failing document I can't help you.

Comment: Sorry. That was a typo. I included the .xdy file without filecontents. Maybe the real world example I added makes the problem clear.

Comment: Ah, you have spaces before the headings. You will have to provide the code of the real world example.

Comment: Still you can see the spaces before the headings in the MWE, albeit not to the same extreme extent. How do I prevent this 'holes'?

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Adding \leavemode provided the solution I was looking for! I'm very thankful you helped me out!