# Unwanted white spaces between index entries

Tags: spacing, indexing, imakeidx, vertical-spacing, idxlayout

I have a very long index and I'm using a layout which you can find here, with an MWE: [Fix the layout of index with imakeidx: a new implementation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/539062/41963).

It prints here and here unwanted white spaces between the entries: I tryied the method of this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375915/41963), but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to avoid unwanted vertical spaces between index entries?

Here is an MWE, but obviously the problem presents itself with a very long index, which is that of my book:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.mst}
item_0 "\n\n \\item "
item_1 " \\firstlevel "
item_2 " \\secondlevel "
item_01 " \\firstlevel "
item_x1 " \\firstlevel "
item_12 " \\secondlevel "
item_x2 " \\secondlevel "
delim_0 ":~"
delim_1 ":~"
delim_2 ":~"
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside, openright]{article}

\usepackage[top=49.5mm,bottom=52.5mm,inner=39mm,outer=39mm, headheight=4mm, headsep=6mm, marginparwidth=14mm, marginparsep=2mm, nofoot]{geometry}


\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX, NoCommon}}


\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\setotherlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{latin}

\widowpenalty=500 
\clubpenalty=100

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{idxlayout}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_ale_index_item_seq
\seq_new:N \l_ale_index_subitem_seq
\tl_new:N \l_ale_index_author_tl
\tl_new:N \l_ale_index_work_tl
\dim_new:N \l_ale_index_indent_dim

\cs_set_protected:cpn { @idxitem } #1 \par
 {
  \tl_if_in:nnTF { #1 } { \firstlevel }
   {
    \tl_if_in:nnTF { #1 } { \secondlevel }
     {
      \ale_index_secondlevel:n  { #1 } \par
     }
     {
      \ale_index_firstlevel:n  { #1 } \par
     }
   }
   {
    \ale_index_nolevel:n  { #1 } \par
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \ale_index_nolevel:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:NVn \l_ale_index_item_seq \c_colon_str { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_ale_index_item_seq \l_ale_index_author_tl
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { \l_ale_index_author_tl, }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_ale_index_indent_dim { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
  \par\hangindent\l_ale_index_indent_dim
  \l_ale_index_author_tl, \seq_use:Nn \l_ale_index_item_seq { }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { NV }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \ale_index_secondlevel:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_ale_index_item_seq { \firstlevel } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_ale_index_item_seq \l_ale_index_author_tl 
  \l_ale_index_author_tl\par
  \seq_map_function:NN \l_ale_index_item_seq \ale_index_subitem:n
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \ale_index_subitem:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_ale_index_subitem_seq { \secondlevel } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_ale_index_subitem_seq \l_ale_index_work_tl
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { \l_ale_index_work_tl,~ }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_ale_index_indent_dim { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
  \par\hangindent=2em
  \quad\l_ale_index_work_tl,~\seq_use:Nn \l_ale_index_subitem_seq { ;\hspace{.3em plus 3em  minus 1em} }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \ale_index_firstlevel:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_ale_index_item_seq { \firstlevel } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_ale_index_item_seq \l_ale_index_author_tl
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { \l_ale_index_author_tl,~ }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_ale_index_indent_dim { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
 \par\hangindent=1em
  \l_ale_index_author_tl,~\seq_use:Nn \l_ale_index_item_seq { ;\hspace{.3em plus 3em minus 1em} }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff




\makeindex[name=1,options=-s \jobname.mst]
\makeindex[name=2,options=-s \jobname.mst]
\makeindex[name=3,options=-s \jobname.mst]
\makeindex[name=4,options=-s \jobname.mst]

\newcommand*{\cose}[1]{\index[1]{#1}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand*{\parole}[1]{\index[2]{#1}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand*{\autori}[1]{\index[4]{#1}\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

text



\autori{Author!Work1!1,15} 
\autori{Author!Work1!9,32}
\autori{Author!Work1!1,12} 
\autori{Author!Work1!9,22}
\autori{Author!Work1!1,25} 
\autori{Author!Work1!9,31}
\autori{Author!Work2!2,24} 
\autori{Author!Work2!5,11}
\autori{Author!Work2!2,25} 
\autori{Author!Work2!5,12}
\autori{Author!Work1!11,42}

\autori{Author2!4,34}
\autori{Author3!6,12} 
\autori{Author3!9,4}
\autori{Author4!9,4}
\autori{Author4!9,5}
\autori{Author4!2,6}
\autori{Author5!2,34}
\autori{Author6!2,4}
\autori{Author7!2,4}
\autori{Author8!2,12} 
\autori{Author 123456!2,12} 
\autori{Author 123456!2,13} 
\autori{Author 123456!2,14} 
\autori{Author 123456!2,15} 

\autori{Author123 (ed. Author10)!Op. XYZ!2,45} 
\autori{Author123 (ed. Author10)!Op. XYZ!2,46} 
\autori{Author123 (ed. Author10)!Op. XYZ!2,47} 
\autori{Author323 (ed. Author10)!Op. XYZ!2,48} 
\autori{Author232 (ed. Author10)!Op. XYZ!2,49} 
\autori{Author933 (ed. Author10)!Op. XYZ!2,50} 

\autori{Author9 (ed. Author10)!Op. XYZ!2,45} 
\autori{Author9 (ed. Author10)!Op. XYZ!2,46} 
\autori{Author9 (ed. Author10)!Op. XYZ!2,47} 
\autori{Author9 (ed. Author10)!Op. XYZ!2,48} 
\autori{Author9 (ed. Author10)!Op. XYZ!2,49} 
\autori{Author9 (ed. Author10)!Op. XYZ!2,52} 
\autori{Author9 (ed. Author10)!Op. XYZ!2,42} 
\autori{Author9 (ed. Author10)!Op. XYZ!2,4446} 
\autori{Author9 (ed. Author10)!Op. XYZ!2,465} 
\autori{Author9 (ed. Author10)!Op. XYZ!2,443343} 
\autori{Author9 (ed. Author10)!Op. XYZ!3,423433} 
\autori{Author9 (ed. Author10)!Op. XYZ!3,534341} 
\autori{Author9 (ed. Author10)!Op. XYZ!3,4446} 
\autori{Author9 (ed. Author10)!Op. XYZ!3,465} 
\autori{Author9 (ed. Author10)!Op. XYZ!3,443} 
\autori{Author9 (ed. Author10)!Op. XYZ!3,423} 
\autori{Author9 (ed. Author10)!Op. XYZ!3,51} 

\printindex[4]

\end{document}
```

Here an example:

[image]

Comment: Why do you expect us to go searching around for bits of code? Please show what *you* have tried. --- GOM

Comment: @PeterWilson I added an MWE, but obviously the problem presents itself with a very long index, which is that of my book

Comment: Is the vertical space between entries consistent within a column (just different in different columns), or does it vary between different entries in the same column?  If consistent within a column, the only way to make it consistent seems to me to be to use `\raggedbottom`, which is definitely inelegant.  Better to try to break entries, as you suggested earlier.  (It's not easy for me to test, but I'll try.)

Comment: It occurs here and here just after an entry, as you can see in the image I added in my question

Comment: Aha!  although the image is blurry, it seems that these large gaps are between groups where the initial letter changes.  Is this correct?  If so, that is an easy fix.  It is a dimension set by the command `\indexspace`.  And that can be reset.  (I haven't yet managed to find where it is set.)

Comment: Yes! I'm sorry, I hadn't noticed! How could I do?

Comment: In `article.cls`, this is the definition of `\indexspace`: `\newcommand\indexspace{\par \vskip 10\p@ \@plus5\p@ \@minus3\p@\relax}`.  If you want to eliminate it entirely, then `\renewcommand{\indexspace}{\par}`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I managed to solve it. Could you write it as an answer?