# Setting the General Space Between the Letter Groups in an Index with \Indexspace

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, makeindex, vertical-spacing, idxlayout

**Update** In light of David Carlisle's very helpful comment providing a simple, efficient solution to setting the space between letter groups in an `idxlayout` index, I have modified the title a bit to better reflect the original question. Although David Carlisle's comment responds quite nicely to the question posed, I would still like to learn, if possible, (in reference to Ulrike Fischer's remark in another post as later noted) how the objective might be accomplished with `\indexspace`.

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\makeindex
\usepackage[]{idxlayout}


\begin{document}
\LARGE
Some words.\index{HEADING1! Subheading! Index entry1.}

Some words.\index{HEADING2! Subheading! Index entry2.}

Some more words.\index{NEXT SET OF HEADINGS1! Subheading! Index entry1.}

Some more words.\index{NEXT SET OF HEADINGS2! Subheading! Index entry2.}
\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

which produces the index

[image]

As one can see, there is not much space between the "H" groupings and the "N" groupings. I would like to, as simply as possible, increase the vertical space between the letter groupings.

Trying to find a way that may have already been prescribed on this site, I came across the post, [Vertical spacing in index with idxlayout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375885/vertical-spacing-in-index-with-idxlayout?rq=1) in which Ulrike Fischer declares "The general space between the letter groups are set by \indexspace which you could redefine if you want"; but the answer given pursues an alternative route.

QUESTION: How may one specify the said space using `\indexspace`? Is it as simple a matter as declaring something like "\indexspace=20pt"? If so, how\where? I have not found an answer yet.

(No texindy please.)

Thank you.

Comment: all your examples include the `idxlayout` package but none of them so far have used it. `texdoc idxlayout` on page 4 documents the key `initsep` as "vertical space between index groups with differing initial letters"

Comment: @David Carlisle Many thanks for pointing out this very simple alternative.